# Technique to get a more organic shape from a base model head

Tags: modeling

I am a novice, and have been watching this old Maya video to practice modeling faces.

Around the 30sec mark the modeler uses something like **vertex relaxing after adding cuts to the brow, chin, and ear areas**, completely improving the head to a more organic shape.

https://youtu.be/ac4qV2uIF3Q?t=29

[image]
[image]

How would I achieve this in Blender2.9? I have discovered that the relax tool has been merged into the Mesh:Loop Tools Add-on, but cannot achieve similar results.

Comment: Please add more specific details to your question. The video is a timelapse and many operations are done in few seconds.

Comment: Welcome to BSE. You can improve your question and make it more relevant for future readers if you change the title to something like "Technique to get a more organic shape from a base model head?". That makes your question easier to find. (Nobody will search for the term "Unknown technique" if you have a problem with the shape. ;-) Add a screenshot of what you have tried & expect or at least from the video (so your Q does not rely on external resources that can go lost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The head is box-modeled from a uv-sphere. The video is a timelapse but you can follow along if you stop it after each step, basically after each second ;-)

Most of the time you only have to move vertices along the axis a bit and add new geometry with the knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd> in Edit mode). For the neck (a cylinder) add edge loops with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

[image: image with two heads]

### How to Get It In Shape

The mentioned relaxation of the vertices can be achieved in Blender with the `Smooth brush`, which also works with low-poly mesh. After you added the new edges switch to the `Sculpt Mode`. Select the brush with a very small strength (~`0.08`) and touch the top of the head, the forehead, cheeks and chin area.  The Smooth brush reduces the volume and the chin will get smaller if you touch it a few times.

The flat area of the ears can be pulled out slightly if you pull the pole and the vertices around it to the side. Use the `Snake Hook brush` or `Elastic Deform brush`. This will give the head a rounder appearance.

Then pull the outer vertex of the cheekbone downwards with the Snake Hook brush (alternatively, you can do this in `Edit mode`). Finally, move both vertices that form the cheekbone a bit forward, along the y-axis, to give them more volume.

That's it.

Later, when the mesh has a higher density, you can use the Smooth brush to smooth it, the `Elastic Deform` and the `Inflate` brushes to restore the volume and to adjust the shape.

The relax tool (in the Loop Tool add-on) is great to smooth edge loops. For example when you messed up the lips or the eyelids.

It is best to see the changes in the frontal view:

[image: frontal view]

[image]